# Express body-parser handling checkbox arrays on forms

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, body-parser

I have an HTML form with an array of checkboxes (using `[]` naming). I need to be able to process this with *express*. I'm using *body-parser*.

The problem is that unchecked checkboxes don't submit a value, and at the same time, *body-parser* seems to remove "holes" in arrays by simply packing the values into an array in order of indices, but ignoring the indices themselves. (Update: Actually it looks like [*qs* is the culprit](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/211#issuecomment-266324971)).

Consider this full example, which displays a form and responds with a JSON dump of the submitted data:

Install:

```
npm install express body-parser
```

index.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var site = express();

site.use(require("body-parser").urlencoded({extended:true}));

site.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/test.html");
});

site.post("/form", function (req, res) {
    res.json(req.body);
});

site.listen(8081);
```

test.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="/form">
            <input type="checkbox" name="option[0]" value="1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="option[1]" value="1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="option[2]" value="1"><br>
            <input type="text" name="text[0]"><br>
            <input type="text" name="text[1]"><br>
            <input type="text" name="text[2]"><br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In that example, if I were to check only `option[1]`, I verify that the index is set correctly by inspecting the request in Chrome, body is:

```
option[1]:1
text[0]:
text[1]:
text[2]:
```

Yet body-parser collapses the `option` array and produces the following in `req.body`:

```
{"option":["1"],"text":["","",""]}
```

As you can see, `text` has all three, but `option` has only one item. Similarly, if I were to check `option[0]` and `option[2]`, the request body would look like:

```
option[0]:1
option[2]:1
text[0]:
text[1]:
text[2]:
```

But it would be parsed to:

```
{"option":["1","1"],"text":["","",""]}
```

I lose all information about which checkbox was checked.

My question is, **how do I do this?** What I *want* to happen is, e.g.:

- With `checkbox[1]` checked:

  ```
  {"option":[null,"1",null],"text":["","",""]}
  ```
- With `checkbox[0]` and `checkbox[2]` checked:

  ```
  {"option":["1",null,"1"],"text":["","",""]}
  ```

I'm not actually married to `null` and `"1"`, I just need falsey and truthy.

Also, **it is important that I not lose information about how many checkboxes *should* be in the array**. For example, if I were to give each checkbox a unique value, I suppose I could translate `"option":["0","1"]` into an array of boolean values, except I would lose the knowledge that the array is of size 3 (with the 3rd value false in that case) -- although I guess I could add e.g. a hidden input like `numberOfCheckboxes=3`, but... this kind of mapping is cumbersome and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Related issues posted: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/211, https://github.com/ljharb/qs/issues/181

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My approach requires no javascript on client side.
Add hidden fields as many as your checkboxes with same names

body parser will parse checked items as array and string others

I meant

```
<input type="hidden" name="option[0]" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="option[1]" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="option[2]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="option[0]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="option[1]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="option[2]" value="1">
```

If your option[1] is checked then body parser will parse it like

```
{option:['0', ['0', '1'], '0']}
```

And here is the modifier

```
req.body.option = req.body.option.map(item => (Array.isArray(item) && item[1]) || null);
```

so now body will be

```
{option: [null, '1', null]}
```

Comment: Clever, and simple. I like it. It would be nice if I could somehow stop body-parser from collapsing arrays, but I think I'm going to go with this. Thanks!

Comment: It'll always store arrays in the order they are on the form, right? So there's never a risk of e.g. `['1','0']`? Although that's easy enough to handle, I could just check if the array length is 2 in the `map` function instead.

Comment: I think it depends on where your hidden fields are placed. If you placed the hidden fields just after form opening tag or just before checkboxes then yes @JasonC order will be same.

Comment: that's simple yet smart! thank you, if any one tries this and runs into error: cannot use .map of undefined , then change from false to app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution (not the best) is that you can add hidden input's with different ids and then check them when the check-boxes on the page get unchecked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option[0]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="option[1]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="option[2]" value="1">

<input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="hiddenOption[0]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="hiddenOption[1]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="hiddenOption[2]" value="1">
```

And before submit:

```
$('input[name^=option]').each(function () {      
  if(!this.checked) {
    var name = "input[name=\'hiddenOption" + this.name.replace('option', '') + "\']";
    console.log(name);
    $(name).prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

And then based on that you can figure out which ones are not ticked.

https://plnkr.co/edit/mJCbtgQnQudHGrUzAz3A?p=preview

Comment: So if only `option[1]` were checked, then it would post `option[0]:0,option[1]:1,option[2]:0` and `hiddenOption[0]:1,hiddenOption[1]:0,hiddenOption[2]:1`? That wouldn't work, though. It would have the same problem. Body-parser would collapse it into `option:["1"],hiddenOption["1","1"]` and I'd lose info about the original array indices still.